# C read large dataset turn out slow in HDF5 (using HD5_read)

Tags: c, hdf5

I have a large table in the dataset about 40 million rows. In Python, reading the file with h5py library is very fast. However, I need to do the readings in my C++ codes. So I tried the following codes but it just froze (too slow) when I run it. I have tested the code for smaller cases with about 1000 rows and it was good. I have no idea what should I do. Hope anyone can help. Thank you very much. Here are my codes:

```
#define NFIELDS  (hsize_t)  2
#define NRECORDS (hsize_t) 44169408

int main(){
    hid_t file_id, dataset_id, group_id; /* identifiers */
    herr_t status;
    float dset_data[NRECORDS][NFIELDS];

    file_id = H5Fopen("large.h5", H5F_ACC_RDONLY, H5P_DEFAULT);

    dataset_id = H5Dopen(file_id, "ds", H5P_DEFAULT);
    status = H5Dread(dataset_id, H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL,
            H5P_DEFAULT, dset_data);

    /* Close the dataset. */
    H5Dclose(dataset_id);
    /* Close the file. */
    H5Fclose(file_id);

    printf("OK\n");



   for (int i =0; i< 44169408; ++i){
        printf("%f, %f\n", dset_data[i][0], dset_data[i][1]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it without outputting all 44 million rows? I would expect the output to take longer than the actual reading of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct and should be fast (assuming that the data in the file is also stored as floating-point values, otherwise the datatype conversion could be slowing your I/O down a little).  I'm betting it's the output that's hurting your performance.